# JavaCV Vs OpenCV from Runtime point of View

Tags: java, android, opencv, runtime, javacv

I am building an Android App that includes image processing techniques. From the Runtime point of view, which is better JavaCV or OpenCV ?

Answer (score 5):

Their runtime overhead seems to be about the same, but the android-opencv wrappers do not give access to raw data via direct NIO buffers, rendering custom processing in Java a lot less efficient. JavaCV is more efficient for those tasks. Being the author of JavaCV, I also like its API better :) It's closer to the original C/C++ API than android-opencv.

EDIT: Another difference is that android-opencv forces users to use the NDK and JNI to write functions. Since JavaCV is based on [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/), we can write native functions more easily without having to deal with neither the NDK nor JNI.

Answer (score 0):

Writing native code using Android NDK will usually be much faster than using the SDK.
You can find nice tutorial [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html), using opencv with NDK. Notice that with NDK framework you have access to openGL functions.

Answer (score 0):

JavaCV is just a Java wrapper around the native OpenCV library.  OpenCV does provide a Java/SWIG binding.  I have used both bindings and didn't see a significant difference between the two.

If you are writing a native only app go with native OpenCV.